# App crash log, what does it mean?

Tags: ios, crash

The app/game works pretty well, I haven't had any problems with it until yesterday afternoon. I tried debugging it and came upon a log.

Here is the crash report, the crash occurs on thread 10 and seems to be mainlu from a libsystem_kernel?

```
{"name":"Republique","bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1 (11D167)","bundleID":"com.Camouflaj.Republique","version":"2.3 (2.3)","app_name":"Republique"}
Incident Identifier: 5C4745DF-C264-4500-B6C7-D3798BDEC5C8
CrashReporter Key:   db19cad0c844cd05448ae8dbdd6a2811583be586
Hardware Model:      iPad2,4
Process:             Republique [134]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/D5A65A90-AFBF-4667-8B91-A713DA84D000/Republique.app/Republique
Identifier:          com.Camouflaj.Republique
Version:             2.3 (2.3)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-06-20 12:10:33.209 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 7.1 (11D167)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000004
Triggered by Thread:  10

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5d0b2 0x38a59000 + 16562
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59d92 0x38a59000 + 3474
2   Republique                      0x01472ba8 0x1d000 + 21322664
3   Republique                      0x0147288c 0x1d000 + 21321868
4   Republique                      0x01407e20 0x1d000 + 20885024
5   Republique                      0x01407d98 0x1d000 + 20884888
6   Republique                      0x01408554 0x1d000 + 20886868
7   Republique                      0x01408628 0x1d000 + 20887080
8   Republique                      0x01406478 0x1d000 + 20878456
9   Republique                      0x01243050 0x1d000 + 19030096
10  Republique                      0x0117fb24 0x1d000 + 18230052
11  Republique                      0x0117f9f4 0x1d000 + 18229748
12  QuartzCore                      0x2fe34dee 0x2fdda000 + 372206
13  QuartzCore                      0x2fe34b98 0x2fdda000 + 371608
14  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x32ba275a 0x32b9c000 + 26458
15  IOKit                           0x2e63744e 0x2e634000 + 13390
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2d90cef6 0x2d879000 + 605942
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2d917ab4 0x2d879000 + 649908
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2d917a4e 0x2d879000 + 649806
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2d916222 0x2d879000 + 643618
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2d880f4a 0x2d879000 + 32586
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2d880d2e 0x2d879000 + 32046
22  GraphicsServices                0x3277a65e 0x32771000 + 38494
23  UIKit                           0x301cc168 0x3015e000 + 450920
24  Republique                      0x0002157c 0x1d000 + 17788
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x3893cab4 0x3893b000 + 6836

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389df808 0x389df000 + 2056
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x38921078 0x38916000 + 45176
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x38920dfe 0x38916000 + 44542

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f2c70 0x389df000 + 81008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59bda 0x38a59000 + 3034
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59a94 0x38a59000 + 2708

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389dfa58 0x389df000 + 2648
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389df854 0x389df000 + 2132
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2d917896 0x2d879000 + 649366
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2d915fbc 0x2d879000 + 643004
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2d880f4a 0x2d879000 + 32586
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2d880d2e 0x2d879000 + 32046
6   Foundation                      0x2e2c0082 0x2e267000 + 364674
7   Foundation                      0x2e335a5a 0x2e267000 + 846426
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389dfaa8 0x389df000 + 2728
1   Republique                      0x01926f74 0x1d000 + 26255220
2   Republique                      0x018835b8 0x1d000 + 25585080
3   Republique                      0x01902a5c 0x1d000 + 26106460
4   Republique                      0x0191fa88 0x1d000 + 26225288
5   Republique                      0x0193bcb0 0x1d000 + 26340528
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389dfaa8 0x389df000 + 2728
1   Republique                      0x014716ec 0x1d000 + 21317356
2   Republique                      0x01472908 0x1d000 + 21321992
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389dfaa8 0x389df000 + 2728
1   Republique                      0x01652094 0x1d000 + 23285908
2   Republique                      0x0166ed20 0x1d000 + 23403808
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389dfa58 0x389df000 + 2648
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389df854 0x389df000 + 2132
2   AudioToolbox                    0x2d2fc7f6 0x2d1ef000 + 1103862
3   AudioToolbox                    0x2d2ff8dc 0x2d1ef000 + 1116380
4   AudioToolbox                    0x2d23cfc0 0x2d1ef000 + 319424
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f2544 0x389df000 + 79172
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38963988 0x3895a000 + 39304
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x389638d6 0x3895a000 + 39126
3   Republique                      0x01651c30 0x1d000 + 23284784
4   Republique                      0x0166ed04 0x1d000 + 23403780
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389dfa58 0x389df000 + 2648
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389df854 0x389df000 + 2132
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2d917896 0x2d879000 + 649366
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2d915fbc 0x2d879000 + 643004
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2d880f4a 0x2d879000 + 32586
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2d8c4a3e 0x2d879000 + 309822
6   CoreMotion                      0x2df3e3a8 0x2df05000 + 234408
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720


Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f21f0 0x389df000 + 78320
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5c792 0x38a59000 + 14226
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x389a2fd8 0x3895a000 + 298968
3   Republique                      0x01840480 0x1d000 + 25310336
4   Republique                      0x0182fdf0 0x1d000 + 25243120
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x38a56f90 0x38a53000 + 16272
6   Republique                      0x014240d4 0x1d000 + 21000404
7   Republique                      0x01423e50 0x1d000 + 20999760
8   Republique                      0x01423d70 0x1d000 + 20999536
9   Republique                      0x0142ebc0 0x1d000 + 21044160
10  Republique                      0x0142ea24 0x1d000 + 21043748
11  Republique                      0x01427d50 0x1d000 + 21015888
12  Republique                      0x01427a24 0x1d000 + 21015076
13  Republique                      0x01426110 0x1d000 + 21008656
14  Republique                      0x01418d24 0x1d000 + 20954404
15  Republique                      0x01416130 0x1d000 + 20943152
16  Republique                      0x01415eec 0x1d000 + 20942572
17  Republique                      0x0146265c 0x1d000 + 21255772
18  Republique                      0x0145d93c 0x1d000 + 21236028
19  Republique                      0x01408a88 0x1d000 + 20888200
20  Republique                      0x014081c0 0x1d000 + 20885952
21  Republique                      0x01407e70 0x1d000 + 20885104
22  Republique                      0x01472908 0x1d000 + 21321992
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f1f2c 0x389df000 + 77612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5af22 0x38a59000 + 7970
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5bd60 0x38a59000 + 11616
3   Republique                      0x011a9a84 0x1d000 + 18401924
4   Republique                      0x011c0910 0x1d000 + 18495760
5   Republique                      0x011ab718 0x1d000 + 18409240
6   Republique                      0x011ac48c 0x1d000 + 18412684
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f1f2c 0x389df000 + 77612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5af22 0x38a59000 + 7970
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5bd60 0x38a59000 + 11616
3   Republique                      0x011a9a84 0x1d000 + 18401924
4   Republique                      0x011c0910 0x1d000 + 18495760
5   Republique                      0x011ab718 0x1d000 + 18409240
6   Republique                      0x011ac48c 0x1d000 + 18412684
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f1f2c 0x389df000 + 77612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5af22 0x38a59000 + 7970
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5bd60 0x38a59000 + 11616
3   Republique                      0x011a9a84 0x1d000 + 18401924
4   Republique                      0x011c0910 0x1d000 + 18495760
5   Republique                      0x011ab718 0x1d000 + 18409240
6   Republique                      0x011ac48c 0x1d000 + 18412684
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f1f2c 0x389df000 + 77612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5af22 0x38a59000 + 7970
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5bd60 0x38a59000 + 11616
3   Republique                      0x011a9a84 0x1d000 + 18401924
4   Republique                      0x011c6a4c 0x1d000 + 18520652
5   Republique                      0x011ab718 0x1d000 + 18409240
6   Republique                      0x011ac48c 0x1d000 + 18412684
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f2544 0x389df000 + 79172
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38963988 0x3895a000 + 39304
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x389638d6 0x3895a000 + 39126
3   Republique                      0x011ac588 0x1d000 + 18412936
4   Republique                      0x011b2c58 0x1d000 + 18439256
5   Republique                      0x011ab718 0x1d000 + 18409240
6   Republique                      0x011ac48c 0x1d000 + 18412684
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f1f2c 0x389df000 + 77612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5af22 0x38a59000 + 7970
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5bd60 0x38a59000 + 11616
3   Republique                      0x011a9a84 0x1d000 + 18401924
4   Republique                      0x011c0910 0x1d000 + 18495760
5   Republique                      0x011ab718 0x1d000 + 18409240
6   Republique                      0x011ac48c 0x1d000 + 18412684
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f1f2c 0x389df000 + 77612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5af22 0x38a59000 + 7970
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5bd60 0x38a59000 + 11616
3   Republique                      0x011a9a84 0x1d000 + 18401924
4   Republique                      0x011c0910 0x1d000 + 18495760
5   Republique                      0x011ab718 0x1d000 + 18409240
6   Republique                      0x011ac48c 0x1d000 + 18412684
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389dfa58 0x389df000 + 2648
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389df854 0x389df000 + 2132
2   AudioToolbox                    0x2d2fc7f6 0x2d1ef000 + 1103862
3   AudioToolbox                    0x2d2ff8dc 0x2d1ef000 + 1116380
4   AudioToolbox                    0x2d23cfc0 0x2d1ef000 + 319424
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b916 0x38a59000 + 10518
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a5b886 0x38a59000 + 10374
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59aa0 0x38a59000 + 2720

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f2c70 0x389df000 + 81008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59bda 0x38a59000 + 3034
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59a94 0x38a59000 + 2708

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f2c70 0x389df000 + 81008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59bda 0x38a59000 + 3034
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59a94 0x38a59000 + 2708

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389f2c70 0x389df000 + 81008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59bda 0x38a59000 + 3034
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a59a94 0x38a59000 + 2708

Thread 10 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x38995aa9
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x0669d000      r6: 0x0000000b      r7: 0x0669c8c0
    r8: 0x05294e00    r9: 0x3a9b6e30     r10: 0x0669caf0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x0669c8b4      lr: 0x38a5c797      pc: 0x389f21f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: Have you tried to symbolicate this crash log?

Comment: No, I haven't attempted to symbolicate the log.

Comment: Attempt to symbolicate the log.

Comment: This whole conversation is very strange :)

Comment: @kovpas I don't know where you have been but trust me, things much stranger than this happen. OK, mostly in bars late at night—which is a good reason to be in bars late at night. :-) Oh wait, you are from Amsterdam, never mind and say Hi to Mike.